# How can I see how much space I am using on my Dropbox for Business account?

Tags: windows-7, dropbox

I can see how much space I use in my personal account, but for Business account I only see the space used by all users, not just me:

[image]

The only way I have found so far is re-installing Dropbox, and I'll have a warning at the beginning of the installation that with how much space I use:

[image]

How can I see how much space I am using on my Dropbox for Business account without re-installing Dropbox?

The website isn't more informative:

[image]

Opening my local Dropbox folder & get Windows to tell me its size (right click/Properties) won't work as I don't synchronize all my folders.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just open your local Dropbox folder & get Windows to tell you its size - right click/Properties ?

Comment: Thanks but it won't work in my case as I don't synchronize all my folders. Sorry I should have mentioned this in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Google says 0.4% of 3,600,000.0 GB is supposed to be 14.4 TB.

I got these figures off your first screenshot.

Rounding error perhaps? 14.4 TB very off from 548.2 GB

[image]

Comment: Thanks but that's the space used by all users of this Business account, not just me :/

Comment: Go to dropbox forum and ask for feature request to show individual business user space used and quota